# How on python3 load full page?

Tags: python-3.x

There is a page that does not fully load when I request the page. The page 'loads itself' while scrolling down the page.

I try to load page with this method:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen('url').read()
```

But this only loads the head of the page, without the content which loads when scrolling down the page in the browser.

How do you fully load the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't provide much details, nor the URL you speaking about, so I will try to guess what issue you are facing (and I am quite sure it will hit the core of your problem) :

> **You have already the full page, but are not aware of it.**

Try to load in the Internet browser what you have got and there is a high chance that you will be surprised to see the "whole" page.

Things are often not as they look like at the first glance ...

There are HTML pages full of text and images which actual content is no more than a link to a Javascript file. The content you see in an Internet browser is then created from that script which must be executed in order to create the page you see.

**To get the full "content" of pages as you see it in an Internet browser you must simulate the behavior of the Internet browser and load also all files the loaded page links to and execute all the Javascripts in this page catching their output and performing what an Internet browser will perform when running these scripts.**

The above fact makes it possible for web-page designers to stop people who just learned a bit how to program getting a web-page content by loading an URL from downloading their page content without usage of an Internet browser.

**To see it yourself what it is all about don't allow your Internet browser to create cookies, execute scripts and load any further content not being the actual pure content of the page you are loading.**

Comment: Sorry for my small count of details. I have a page which looks like Facebook news page - it not loads full when you open it, but when you scroll page new news appear(loads more content)